# WordPress sub domain htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress

Well I did a wordpress installation with the newer version now available at dere website..

I did my installation at a subdomain: foo.abc.com

the problem came with the permalink which do not work dere bec of the htaccess file.

Can any one suggest me how to do that, i need to have only the category/postname

Till now i am able to do foo.abc.com/index.php/category/postname - I don't want index.php in it.

I have used this htacess file:

```
# disable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please correct me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand the problem, but I'll try and throw out a few solutions.

1. In the Wordpress back-end, under the General Settings Tab- have you set the "Blog address (URL)" and "WordPress address (URL)" to the correct domain? This may write the correct .htaccess setting for you.
2. If you are trying to do something fancier with the domain such as category.blog.com/post_id, perhaps take a look at the WP Subdomains plugin.